# how to solve Cannot find a version of 'com.google.android.material:material' that satisfies the version constraints

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, dependencies, material-design, android-espresso

I am working in espresso test and I needed this following dependency:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.2.0'
```

for recycler-view to complete the test, but when I add this dependency I got this error :

> Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Cannot find a version of >'com.google.android.material:material' that satisfies the version >constraints: 
>     Dependency path 'myproject:app:unspecified' --> >'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
>     Constraint path 'myproject:app:unspecified' --> >'com.google.android.material:material:{strictly 1.0.0-beta01}' because >of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0->beta01

I can understand that this error is because this  following dependency:

```
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
```

and I can solve it by changing the material dependency to other version but the problem if I change the material dependency the design will missed up, I dont want to change it

I already tried to use lower version of the esspreso-contrib to solve it but still this error keeps appears

I really don't want to change the material dependency and I need the test, so please anyone know to solve it, appreciate that

thanks in advance

[edit] Sorry did not mention that the app is running fine without errors but only when I run the test this error appears

Comment: implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01' add the dependency in your project.

Comment: @RachitMishra I didnt get you, its already there in my project... its the cause of the error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid I've been unable to reproduce your error in a test project.

However my first thought would be a [transative dependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html) issue as I suspect that espresso-contrib is pulling and sharing an outdated version of material (1.0.0).

This may be an [issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/issues/252) which some of the android x testing util libraries share.

Try replacing:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.2.0'
```

With:

```
androidTestImplementation ('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.2.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.material', module: 'material'
}
```